# How to use keycloak to generate an api for a 3rd party

Tags: keycloak, pyramid, api-key

I'm creating a pure REST application that I want either our client or 3rd party clients to connect to and do simple GET, POST, etc requests. However 3rd party clients will use their own authentication so I presume (with keycloak?) I need to generate an api-key for these 3rd party's ?

I've looked online but didn't find much, only this [Issuing "API keys" using Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230634/issuing-api-keys-using-keycloak) but what they said didn't work for me, I don't have the same options.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Start by reading the [authoritative docs](https://www.keycloak.org/documentation.html) before searching SO. Also I recommend reading this recent thread on [OAuth with Pyramid](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pylons-discuss/eMWVq8QYM3M).

Comment: You can either use confidential client or check this library https://github.com/carbonrider/keycloak-api-key-module

Comment: @CuriousMind can you update the readme with keycloak 20+ version. The setting of athentications flows is tough to understand