# keycloak with oauth2 and client credential grant type to authenticate external clients(services/applications) to my public API

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I new to keycloak and oauth2 and I need your help.

I'm planning to develop a public API so my customers client applications/serivces could perform some actions in the system without human interaction. Therfore I need to let them a way to authenticate to the API with a "service-account" and an "API key".

I found that the "oauth2 way" to do it called "2-legged" and it's actually the client credential grant type.

I'm trying to understand how to configure keycloak to achive that. I found the following [stack-overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230634/issuing-api-keys-using-keycloak/53178757#53178757), but the author of the answer wrote in a comment "I haven't worked with Keycloak in a while though, so this approach might be out of date."

As I understand the answer, I need to create a client for each external client with the following configuration:

- Access Type: confidential
- Standard Flow Enabled: OFF
- Direct Access Grants Enabled: OFF
- Service Accounts Enabled: ON

And I need to configure some Scope. Which I don't completely understand.

The external client will get the credentials(client id and a secret) belongs to his specific client.
And in order to perform requests against the public API he will ask keycloak for a valid token and then send the requests with that token to my public API.

My questions are:

1. Is this is the right way to do it using keycloak?
2. Is it possible to configure keycloak in a way that each external client will be configured as a user and not as a client in keycloak but still support in client credential grant type?
3. How my public API can validate the token? I must send a request to keycloak to validate the token? or I can validate it with some certificate?

Please advice, 
Thanks!